# Is the Poynting vector non-zero when two magnets are placed on either side of a charged capacitor?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons

I charge up a parallel-plate capacitor, and put a bar magnet on either side, such that the magnetic field is perpendicular to the electric field.

S = E x B

Do photons start coming out of the capacitor?  If so, where does their energy come from?